# Shopify Customer login form with Vue /Ajax

Tags: vue.js, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to do customer  login with Vue .

I have tried to do something and received respone 200 and 302 still but not working.    I also tried this way : http://web.archive.org/web/20150417052042/http://inside.sauce.ly:80/how-to-build-an-ajax-login-form-...

but same .

```
let productForm = new Vue({
el:".vue-login-form",
data(){
    return{
        form: {
            email: null,
            password: null,
        },
        customerData: null,
    }
},

methods:{
    login(){
        axios.post('/account/login', this.form )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.customerData = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error){
        });

        },
    },
```

})

```
<form action="">
    <div class="form-top">
      <h2>Welcome Back!</h2>
      <p>Please login to your account.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="login-fields">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="email" v-model="form.email" placeholder="Email address">
      </div>
      <div class="input mb-0">
        <input type="password" v-model="form.password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="forgot-pass"><a href="#" type="button" id="ppassword" @Click="showForgot">Forgot Password?</a></div>
      <div class="submit-button">
        <button type="button" @Click="login()">Log In</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: In Shopify  due to Google ReCaptcha you can't login using AJAX.

Comment: i already disabled captcha. and then got 200 response. If that's not possible , is there any other way to do this?